# CakePHP keep data form after validation error

Tags: forms, cakephp, validationerror

When I got a password validation error I show the text  error in the head of my page so I want to keep my fileds data even if I have an validation error. 
I am using redirect so there is another way to do that?

```
public function inscriptioncompte(){
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
                    $posted_data = $this->request->data;
            $this->User->create();
            if($this->checkPassword($posted_data['User']['password'])!="1"){

                $this->Session->setFlash($this->checkPassword($posted_data['User']['password']),'ko');
                $this->User->validationErrors;
                $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
            }
            else {


                    $this->User->set(array(
                        'username'=>$posted_data['User']['username'],
                        'password'=>$posted_data['User']['password'],
                        'group_id'=>3));


                    $datenaissance = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($posted_data['User']['datenaissance']));
                    if($this->User->validates()){
                        if($this->User->save()){
                            $this->Customer->create();
                            $this->Customer->set(array(
                                'user_id'=>$this->User->getLastInsertId(),
                                'nom'=>$posted_data['User']['nom'],
                                'prenom'=>$posted_data['User']['prenom'],
                                'adresse'=>"Pas encore d\'adresse ",
                                'email'=>$posted_data['User']['username'],
                                'datenaissance'=> $datenaissance,
                                'ville'=>$posted_data['User']['ville'],
                                'telephone1'=>$posted_data['User']['telephone1'],
                                'telephone2'=>"",
                                'interet'=>""
                                )
                            );
                            if($this->Customer->save()){
                                $this->Session->setFlash("Verifier votre boite mail afin de valider votre inscription.",'ok');
                                $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
                            }else{
                                $this->Session->setFlash("Une erreur c'est produite lors de votre inscription.",'ko');
                                $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
                            }
                        }else{
                            $this->Session->setFlash("Une erreur c'est produite lors de votre inscription.",'ko');
                            $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
                        }
                    }else{
                        $erreurs = $this->User->invalidFields();
                        $erreurToShow = "";
                        if(isset($erreurs['username']['0']) && !empty($erreurs['username']['0'])){
                            $erreurToShow = $erreurs['username']['0'];
                        }
                        if(isset($erreurs['password']['0']) && !empty($erreurs['password']['0'])){
                            $erreurToShow = $erreurToShow.$erreurs['password']['0'];
                        }
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Erreur : ".$erreurToShow,'ko');
                        $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
                    }

            }
        }

    }
```